# Custom include? method for a substring

Tags: strings, ruby

Task:

> Write a function which returns true if a given substring is found within a given string. If the substring isn't found, then return false.

My implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def custom_include?(string, substring)
    len = substring.size
    last_feasible = string.size - len
    
    for i in 0..last_feasible
        current_slice = string[i...i + len]

        if current_slice == substring
            return true
        end
    end 

    false
end

puts custom_include? "The Ruby Programming Language is amazing!", "Language" # true
puts custom_include? "The Ruby Programming Language is amazing!", "language" # false
puts custom_include? "The Ruby Programming Language is amazing!", "amazing!" # true
puts custom_include? "The Ruby Programming Language is amazing!", "The"      # true 
puts custom_include? "The Ruby Programming Language is amazing!", "Test"     # false
```

Is there a way to avoid the `for`-loop? Should I try to "save" variables?

Using variables make it easier for me to development a solution for such an exercise. Moreover I think it makes the script for readable and understandable. What's your opinion about that approach?

Comment: You could just do `def custom_include?(string, substring) string.include?(substring) end`. Nothing in the task prevents this and it sounds like they just want it as a function instead of a method.

Comment: I would definitely add a test case where the substring is longer than the string.